# Validating values of an ObservableCollection<IDictionary<string, object>>, whose keys are decided or run time?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid, observablecollection

In my program i have an ObservableCollection binded to a datagrid,

`ObservableCollections<IDictionary<string, object>> collectionName = new ...`

Keys of each IDictionary are created on run time ( using a list of strings), so we don't have any of the key value pairs at the compile time,

Hence my question is, how can one apply validation ( ExceptionValidation or DataErrorValidation) on such an ObservableCollection, i have been reading about IDataErrorInfo but there again no Keys are known, how can i access the dynamically created keys (headers of the datagrid columns) to check what validation i need to perform on modified values.

Here is one of the classes using ObservableCollection in my program,

```
public class MinorKey
{
    private ObservableCollection<IDictionary<string, Object>> minorKeyData = new ObservableCollection<IDictionary<string, object>>();
    public ObservableCollection<IDictionary<string, Object>> MinorKeyData
    {
        get { return minorKeyData; }
        set 
        { 
            minorKeyData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }

}
```

i currently don't see a way of doing validation using Exception or DataError Validation.

i saw someone suggesting ValidationRule for this purpose, but the examples i have seen in which class inherits a validationRule class, explicity have predefined properties like in [this example on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validationrule?view=netframework-4.7#Examples)
or may be i am not getting it properly, would appreciate it if someone direct me in a right direction on this.

what i am doing right now?

```
private void minorDataRecordsGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (keyDown)
        {
            if (e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row).ToString() != "")
            {
                string value = e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row).ToString();
                int i = e.Row.GetIndex();
                int j = e.Column.DisplayIndex;
                string header = e.Column.Header.ToString();
                var editedTextBox = e.EditingElement as TextBox;  // getting the new content of the text box 
                MessageBox.Show(i.ToString() + "  " + j.ToString() + "  " + header + "   " + editedTextBox.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no empty value, enter 0 if default value");
            }
            keyDown = false;
        }
    }

    private void minorDataRecordsGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.Tab) 
        {
            keyDown = true;
        }
    }
```

In the code above, first i am checking if any keys are pressed except tab, then  i am getting row and column index of data grid whose cell is modified, header of the column and the newly entered value, using all this information i will perform what ever validation is required, but i want to do it using the proper method.

It will be great help if someone can direct me in the right direction, or if someone thinks there is a possibility i can do this validation using IDataErrorInfo or Exception Validation.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: i want to validate the data that the user enters in the data grid, and when it is invalid i want to notify the user. but in my case, keys of IDictionary are created dynamically using expandoObject() so i don't understand how to apply IDataErrorInfo in such a senario. hope it helps you understand my question.

Comment: Validate the object by checking whether the pair can be added first, i.e. do not add it first.